# Why is fileno failing to return a valid descriptor?

Tags: c, file, file-io, stdio

I'm opening a stream with funopen

```
FILE *fin = funopen(cookie, readfn, NULL, NULL, closefn);
if (fin == NULL)
{
    handle_error();
    return -1;
}
int fdin = fileno(fin);
```

The call to funopen succeeds but `fileno(fin)` returns `-1`.

How can I get the file descriptor? Thanks.

Comment: What does `funopen` do exactly ?

Comment: Note that [funopen](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=3&topic=funopen) is specific to BSD.

Comment: @Sander -- I think it is like `fopen` but more with more `fun`

Comment: @Hogan : looks like it's creating a "fake" stream - that sounds like fun indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FILE` opened with `funopen` (which is not part of any standard, by the way; AFAIK it's a BSD extension) does not have an underlying file descriptor.  It has the cookie *instead*.  I don't know what you wanted the file descriptor for, but you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I'm aware that `funopen` is BSD specific. I needed the descriptor to convert the FILE to an apr_file_t.

Comment: I don't know APR at all, but you should try to find a way to *directly* wrap an `apr_file_t` around whatever this is.  We might be able to give more specific advice if you showed us the definitions of your cookie and read function.

Comment: You could always create a pipe to a separate thread instead of using `funopen`.

Comment: Yes, thats what I'm trying now. I wanted to avoid creating a thread (feels like overhead in this particular situation), but using pipes looks like the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no file connected to funopen, and thus no fd. Try `tmpfile` instead if you need that.